# Identifying dependencies among tables

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Given a table, is there any way to identify all tables which are taking foreign key reference on that table?

The actual scenario goes like this. Given a database, I have a set of C# schema classes which I have to populated from data in the database and stored them onto a cache. All these schemas should always be in sync with the database.

Now, I have two ways to solve the above problem, one is that whenever a database change happens, go and update all the stored schemas which will be very costly. The other is use some heuristic based algo to correctly identify the schema which will be impacted from a db change and update those only.

In order to do implement this, I was thinking of building a `dependency tree/graph` kind of structure where a table `T1` is called as dependent on Table `T2` of `T1` has a `foreign key` constrain on `T2`. So that whenever a change happens in one or more table, I can quickly iterate over the graph and says that these all schemas needs to be updated.

I know that using Data Dictionaries you can find these kind of dependencies but since I am using `Entity Framework`, I'm looking for a way of doing it through `Entity Framework`.

Also, if someone has a better approach of doing the same, share that as well.

Comment: Are you using DB first? What's wrong with doing an "update model from database"?

Comment: New data will always come in database only. From there I have to pull required data and populate C# schemas. What do you mean by "update model from database"?

Comment: @default.kramer: I looked about "update model from Db" and it seems to me something which you do manually, correctly me if I am wrong. Also, I have to do all this stuff from the code in C# and that too inside Azure.

Comment: I thought you were asking how to make sure that the schema in code matches the DB schema (at compile time). Now I see that you are asking how to keep the data in your app's memory synchronized with the data in the DB (at runtime).